# accessing a list of nodes

Tags: haskell, tree

I am currently learning for an exam coming up soon.

We got some functions which we got given for preparing and training.

I want a function giving True if there are excact 2 nodes having the same value.

Given:

```hs
data Tree a = Node a [Tree a] | Leaf a

exercise62 :: Eq a => Tree62 a -> Bool
exercise62 = undefined

exercise62 (Node 5 [Node 6 [Leaf 4], Node 4 [Leaf 3]]) ~> True
exercise62 (Node 5 [(Node 5 [Leaf 4])]) ~~> True
exercise62 (Node 5 [Node 6 [Leaf 4], Node 3 [Leaf 2]]) ~~> False
```

My idea is:

1.) Create a function which will give a list with all values.

2.) Check if there is a value coming twice.

My problem is 1.)

What i tried so far:

```hs
exercise62Helper :: Eq a => Tree a -> [a]
exercise62Helper (Leaf a) = [a]
exercise62Helper (Node a b) = [a] ++ exercise62Helper (head b)
```

I think my problem is `exercise62Helper (head b)` as I am only checking the first element of the list instead of all elements in [Tree a].

But I don't understand how I can excactly access them, usally I would access them via tail but its not possible (or I dont know) because the parameter of the function are `Tree` and not `[Tree]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ca work with [**`concatMap :: Foldable f => (a -> [b]) -> f a -> [b]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:concatMap) to map all the elements of `b` over `exercise62Helper`, and concatenate the results. Your function also does *not* require an `Eq a` type constraint, since regardless whether you can check if two items are equal, you can make a list of these items:

```
exercise62Helper :: Tree a -> [a]
exercise62Helper (Leaf a) = [a]
exercise62Helper (Node a b) = a : concatMap exercise62Helper b
```

You can also work with the [**DeriveFoldable** extension](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/deriving_extra.html#extension-DeriveFoldable), and let Haskell generate a trivial instance of `Foldable` for your type:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFoldable #-}

data Tree a = Node a [Tree a] | Leaf a deriving Foldable
```

the `exercise62Helper` is then a special version of [**`toList :: Foldable f => f a -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:toList):

```
import Data.Foldable(toList)

exercise62Helper :: Tree a -> [a]
exercise62Helper = toList
```